# PHP PDF download is not working properly in mobile

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, download, header

I am creating a web application in Codeigniter 4 in which users can purchase a PDF book. After payment, the user is redirected to a page where he/she can download PDF directly. The page doesn't have any UI. The PDF download is implemented using `headers`. The PDF download function is working perfectly on PC, but on mobile, the file is downloading as an HTML file.

**eg : filename.pdf.html**.

My function is as below

```
public function download()
{
    $file_url = WRITEPATH . 'uploads/file.pdf';
    header("Content-type:application/pdf");
    header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=filename.pdf");
    readfile($file_url);
}
```

I have searched and tried almost all the solutions. But still, the issue is not resolved in mobile.

Comment: You say: _"the file is downloading as an HTML file"_, but that should imply you see garbage in the browser, right? Not HTML, or interpreted HTML, just weird characters? Or do you actually get something to download, but it is a file containing HTML code?!

Comment: @KIKOSoftware It is not HTML code. It is the PDF file itself but it is automatically renamed to .html. I can view the original PDF once I rename the file and open it in Mobile PDF viewer. Weird thing is that the file name is correct on the PC.

Comment: Tested on Android Google Chrome but no problem - work perfectly. What web browser you are using? It might be client side related.

Comment: @vee Same. Android Google Chrome. I have tested in 3-4 phones. Still same.

Comment: It is possible that this happens because some apps. 1. Try again with other web browsers on mobile such as Firefox. 2. Try to remove some app that maybe rename the file such as antivirus or utilities. 3. Test with some emulator that is just Android and necessary apps.

Comment: You may try with your code above (without method name) on a single file. Or try to list the headers that is already response using [`headers_list()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php) to make sure that the `content-type` header is not modified and sent before. Don't forget to add `exit();` after `readfile();` if download is completed and don't want it to continue process anything more.

Comment: @vee adding `exit();` done the job. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue.
Looks like Codeigniter needed `exit()` function after `readfile()`
Thanks to @vee who gave the tip.